# android; loud hissing sound

Tags: audio, codenameone

My android apps occasionally emit an alarmingly loud hissing sound,
presumably when some other sound was supposed to be played.  This
suggests some underlying race condition in the sound manager; but 
I wonder if anyone else has encountered this ?

My sounds are all prerecorded .wav files.

Comment: I have heard such a sound when my code was mistakenly rendering audio using wrong bit depth or wrong endianness, certainly not limited to android but can happen on any platform however once I tweaked my code it does not reappear so may not be your use case

Comment: Share your WAV files. Also what API are you using to play the sound with, MediaPlayer, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest switching to MP3 or AAC both of which are smaller and more deterministic in playback. As Scott mentioned there is probably a discrepancy in the bit depth which is less likely in an encoded file than in a raw file.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the files or the way they're being played.  There are only a handful of them, and they play fine almost every time.